# Python script to continue running

Tags: python, loops, ip, continue

I am new to python programming. I want my code to continue running and continue checking my ip address. `

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

hostname = "192.168.254.102" #example
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
```

## and then check the response...

```
if response == 0:
    print(hostname, 'is up!')
    os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_on.py 1")
else:
    print(hostname, 'is down!')
```

`

Basically, I cant the code to check my phone ip address when i got home then the script will turn on the light. I tested the script and it works well if you run it in the terminal but you need to sudo python scriptname.py first
Thank you

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to run scripts as sudo (sometimes necessary, but very rarely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the python `schedule` [open source project](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def job():   
    import os
    hostname = "192.168.254.102" #example
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
    if response == 0:
        print(hostname, 'is up!')
        os.system("sudo python ../aquarium/nightlight_on.py 1")
    else:
        print(hostname, 'is down!')

import schedule
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
```

And then run your python script as a background process with the unix `&` flag:

```
$ sudo python yourScript.py &
```

You can install schedule with `pip`. You will still have to restart that process when your computer reboots, or make an upstart or systemd job to handle that.

Comment: Hi fofls, I can an error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_ip.py", line 12, in <module>
    import schedule
ImportError: No module named schedule


This is after typing $ sudo python yourScript.py &

ofcourse yourScript.py is the name of my script.

Comment: I sorted it out... It all works fine now... YOur the man.. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks, @MerBalds :) Glad you figured it out